# Parameter \$k\$ for MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, nmos

Is the parameter \$k\$ used for the whole circuit or for every MOSFET in the circuit?

For example the circuit has 2 MOSFETS and \$k = 1mA/V^2\$. If I want to find the \$Id_1\$ and \$Id_2\$, is k = 0.5 per MOSFET in solving \$I_d=k/2*(V_gs-V_th)^2\$ or just use k=1mA/V^2?

Comment: It's not `$I_d_1$` for \$I_{d_1}\$ but `\$I_{d_1}\$` unless of course you meant something else. Please clarify and fix as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Parameter k will depend on the transistor type and W/L of the transistor. So, you need to find out for which transistor type and W/L the parameter k was provided to you. If you have to find the Id of another transistor of same type but different W/L, you cannot use the same k, you'll have to calculate the k applicable to it based on it's W/L ratio.